# setting background highlight on custom button layer

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I am working on an app where I have a custom button class (I found this class here on StackOverflow - credit to the original poster). where I have added a CAShapelayer to the button to give it a shape like the rounded rectangular button. This works well, but I would like to highlight the button when the user holds their finger on it, and I am running into a problem. When I override the highlighted color, it only highlights the layer BEHIND my rounded rectangle layer.

Can someone help me understand what I need to do to make my custom button highlight properly ? I am building this in Swift, in iOS8.1. Thank you much!

**Custom button code:**

```
  public var roundRectCornerRadius: CGFloat = 8 {
        didSet {
            self.setNeedsLayout()
        }
    }

    /// background of the rounded lyer
    public var roundRectColor: UIColor = UIColor.whiteColor() {
        didSet {
            self.setNeedsLayout()
        }
    }

    override public func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        layoutRoundRectLayer()
    }

    // how do i get this into the roundrectlayer?
    override public var highlighted: Bool {

        get {
            return super.highlighted
        }
        set {
            if newValue {
                backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
            }
            else {
                backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
            }
            super.highlighted = newValue
        }
    }


    private var roundRectLayer: CAShapeLayer?

    private func layoutRoundRectLayer() {
        if let existingLayer = roundRectLayer {
            existingLayer.removeFromSuperlayer()
        }
        let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        shapeLayer.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.bounds, cornerRadius: roundRectCornerRadius).CGPath
        shapeLayer.fillColor = roundRectColor.CGColor


        self.layer.insertSublayer(shapeLayer, atIndex: 0)
        self.roundRectLayer = shapeLayer
    }
```